# ActiveAdmin with Rails 4 redirects to localhost in production

Tags: ssl, routes, localhost, activeadmin, production

I'm using the ActiveAdmin gem in a Rails 4 app, and having trouble when it's deployed in production.  It's working fine in development, or when I run it locally in production.

For example, after saving an Asset, instead of redirecting to `https://domainname.com/admin/assets/1`, it redirects to `https://localhost/admin/assets/1`, which doesn't exist, so it blows up.

As far as I can tell, I have things set up correctly.  Here's my routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: redirect_to('/admin')

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
end
```

Things seem to work fine in production mode when I'm running it locally, but not when after it's been deployed behind SSL.

Has anyone else had trouble like this when using SSL with ActiveAdmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the nginx configuration was bad.  Nothing to do with the Rails code at all!

Comment: Hi can you post what the bad configuration was? I am having the exact same problem but I can't spot any problem in my nginx config.

Comment: It's been awhile, but I think it was something to do with the redirect if the request wasn't https.  Sorry if that's vague!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same localhost redirection problem on prod, but only with destroy method. I implemented a redirection that did the trick :

```
controller do
  def destroy
    super do |format|
      redirect_to admin_model_path and return
    end
  end
end
```

I still don't know what was the root cause.